# load scipy interpolation rfb nodes

Tags: python, model, scipy, interpolation

I am having difficulties unterstanding how a system using Rbf interpolation works.

The system basically collects 50 points `(A,B)` that have a mapping to another 50 points `(X,Y)`
Then a bidirectional iterpolation is trained, so new `(X,Y)` points can be converted to `(A,B)` and viceversa.

```
from scipy.interpolate import Rbf

# training of the model
Ai = Rbf(X, Y, A)
Bi = Rbf(X, Y, B)
Xi = Rbf(A, B, X)
Yi = Rbf(A, B, Y)
```

This results into `Ai, Bi, Xi, Yi` being `scipy.interpolate.rbf.Rbf` objects which can be called to predict

```
# now given new (X,Y) points I can calculate the corresponding interpolated (A,B) coords
newX, newY = (5, 2)
pred_A = Ai(newX, newY)
pred_B = Bi(newX, newY)

# same for given new `(A,B)` points, I can calculate the corresponding interpolated `(X,Y)` coords
newA, newB = (5, 2)
pred_X = Xi(newA, newB)
pred_Y = Yi(newA, newB)
```

Each of this interpolation functions has inside a list of nodes, which is the coefficients to be applied to each rbf kernel, and is a list of 50 elements

Now I want to save this model into a file, so it can later be used for predictions.
So I save the nodes of each of the predictors into a dataframe.

```
model = pd.DataFrame(np.array((Ai.nodes, Bi.nodes, Xi.nodes, Yi.nodes)).T,
                     columns=['Ai', 'Bi', 'Xi', 'Yi'])
model.to_csv('model.csv', index=False)
```

Now in another program I want to load this nodes from the csv file, create an rbf interpolation and feed it with this nodes. But I cannot find a method or a way how to do that.

It looks like I cannot create an empty interpolation and feed it later with data, and I don't see a way of setting the nodes into an existing rbf interpolation.

Is there a way, if I have the nodes of a trained rbf interpolation object to create it again without the original training data?

Answer (score 0):

There is no supported way of doing it.

You can look through the `Rbf.__init__` and save enough from the existing interpolator, and reconstruct it later, but that's not guaranteed to not break later. YMMV